# Ocultar/trocar mensagem de erro no console

Tags: jquery, console

Tento pegar por exemplo um arquivo que não existe no meu site, como:

```
try {
    $.getScript('app/controllers/arquivo-errado.js', function(){});
} catch (e) {
    // caso de erro
}
```

É retornado no console o erro:

> GET URL...app/controllers/arquivo-errado.js?_=1484154145345 **404 (Not
>   Found)**

Quero saber como **posso** trocar ou ocultar esse erro, por exemplo, trocar ele por um erro 'Arquivo não existe', ou sem mostrar o erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que não é possível eliminar ou substituir esta mensagem 404 nativa do navegador. Mas:

1) você pode adicionar uma mensagem padrão adicionando um callback `.fail` ao método:

```
$.getScript('app/controllers/arquivo-errado.js')
  .done(function( script, textStatus ) {
    console.log("Arquivo carregado com sucesso :)");
  })
  .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
    console.log("Não foi possível carregar o arquivo :(");
  });
```

2) ou fazer uma espécie de arquivo proxy que passa o arquivo js ao cliente, mas, em caso de não encontrá-lo, apenas renderiza um código 200, sem conteúdo. Desta forma, o browser não entende como 404 e não mostra o erro. Só uma ideia.

Comment: Consegui contornar o erro de outra forma, tendo um arquivo de rotas, mas testei aqui com o arquivo proxy e rodou de boa tambem, obrigado